# What's the default PHP session lifetime?

Tags: php

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [PHP : What is the default lifetime of a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156712/php-what-is-the-default-lifetime-of-a-session)

What's the default session lifetime in PHP? Can it be changed?

Answer (score 2):

You can get your default session life time by doing this:

```
echo ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
```

To set your own session life time or to extend it, do this:

```
ini_set('session.gc_maxlifetime', 30*60); // Can be changed to anything in seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

To get:

```
ini_get('session.gc_maxlifetime');
```

To set:

```
ini_set(‘session.gc_maxlifetime’,SOME_VALUE);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's in your php.ini file. It defaults to 24 minutes, but it's easy to change.

Look for `session.gc_maxlifetime` and set to to the value you want in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

> The default in the php.ini for the session.gc_maxlifetime directive
>   (the "gc" is for garbage collection) is 1440 seconds or 24 minutes.

see: [PHP : What is the default lifetime of a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156712/php-what-is-the-default-lifetime-of-a-session)