# How long will a session variable last if you don't unset it?

Tags: php, apache, session, garbage-collection, session-state

When I store a variable in a session (in php), how long will that variable linger in that file? Will it be there until someone unsets the variable or deletes the file?

**update:** so it is [session.gc-maxlifetime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime)  setting that is set in php.ini file. You can check  your setting by calling phpinfo().  Mine is set to 1440 seconds so 24 minutes. [Might have found a duplicate here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156712/php-what-is-the-default-lifetime-of-a-session), although when googling I didn't find it at first because of the wording.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

By default it will be there 24 minutes. (Which is the default php.ini file setting).

As you commented, this is the setting: http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Comment: Is this the setting you are talking about? http://www.php.net/manual/en/session.configuration.php#ini.session.gc-maxlifetime

Comment: so 24 minutes is the time it last on server by default. How long session cookie will last on the client?

Answer (score 1):

Look in your `php.ini` file. It will tell you exactly how long the default session will last.