# What variable is holding the time that a session can live in PHP?

Tags: php, session

After being inactive for some time in my php application I get kicked out (around 20 minutes).

I am suspecting that it could be a variable in php.ini conf file which is killing the sessions or removing the sessions but I'm not 100% sure if this is something that it has to do with that, at least I can try.

The question is what is the variable responsible for the live of the session?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I expire a PHP session after 30 minutes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/520237/how-do-i-expire-a-php-session-after-30-minutes)

Comment: that post doesn't resolve my question, it's talking about creating a custom script to expire sessions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

php.ini -> session.gc_maxlifetime

The default is 1440 seconds (24 mins)

See this:
[PHP : What is the default lifetime of a session](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/156712/php-what-is-the-default-lifetime-of-a-session)